# Tag 1.10.3 AS base not found in repository docker.io/library/golang

Tags: docker, go, makefile, moby

when i try to compile moby (the latest version 2018.08.07), the outcome like this:

```
docker build   -t "docker-dev:master" -f "Dockerfile" .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 43.28 MB
Step 1 : FROM golang:1.10.3 AS base
Pulling repository docker.io/library/golang
Tag 1.10.3 AS base not found in repository docker.io/library/golang
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

my host machine is : centos 6

```
Linux li1202-249.members.linode.com 4.15.13-x86_64-linode106 #1 SMP Tue Mar 27 14:42:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

my docker version is:

```
[root@li1202-249 ~]# docker version
Client:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.3
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Server:
   Version:      1.9.1
   API version:  1.21
   Go version:   go1.4.3
   Git commit:   a34a1d5
   Built:        Fri Nov 20 17:56:04 UTC 2015
   OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

what's the wrong configuration i had set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Multi-stage builds are a new feature requiring Docker 17.05 or higher on the daemon and client.

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Your (ancient) Docker version doesn't support multi-stage builds. You can update Docker, build everything in one stage, or use the builder pattern described in the article linked above.